# OS X starting a jar as launch item will not read configuration file

Tags: jar, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to run a command

```
java -jar ccu-historian.jar
```

as launch item

When I run the command on the commandline everything is working

When I try to run it as launchAgent via

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.bob.ccuhistorian</string>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>/usr/bin/java</string>
<string>-jar</string>
<string>/Users/user/Applications/ccuhistorian/ccu-historian.jar</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I get the error message that it cannot run

```
13.11.11 15:15:34   com.bob[1445]   15:15:34|SEVERE |Exception: Can't access configuration file ccu-historian.config
```

the file is in the same folder and I tried changing via chmod 777 - no change, and it can be read when calling from the command line - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution:

writing a bash-script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/user/Applications/ccuhistorian/
/usr/bin/java -jar ccu-historian.jar
```

and calling

```
/path/to/script.sh
```

as only parameter to the XML is working, but shouldn't be there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an overengeneering.
But you could read the current path of the Jar file and construct the path of the config file from that.
Problem is, you probably access it with a relative path, but the "java -jar /path/to/your/file" is looking for it in a false directory.